# Can we Call REST api from Azure Serverless Database Stored Procedures

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-application-insights, serverless

Is it possible to call REST Api (Azure Application Insights Api) from Azure Serverless Database Stored Procedures?
It seems, SQL CLR is not available for Azure Serverless Sql Database. Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official document, CLR Stored Procedures are supported only on SQL Database Managed Instances.

At this moment, there's no integration between SQL Database and Event Grid, so your only option is to perform the http request right after the commit operation in your SQL.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/features-comparison